# How to select optimum number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Actually I wrote a Java program for calculating a particular number on the Fibonacci series.

The problem is right now is that I am using number of cores as number of threads required. But I have observed that as the input size increases I get better performance by increasing the number of threads.

Is there an existing formula/Theory on how to divide the problem into multiple threads?

Below is the source code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Fibonacci {
    private static long[] value;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        int n;
        try {
            n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Please enter in the form java n number ");
        }
        value = new long[n + 1];


        long start = System.nanoTime();
        int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
        int result;
        try {
            result = fibonacciSum(n, executorService);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Thread Interuppted ");
        }
        System.out.print(" MultiThreading = " + result);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("\t time = " + (end - start) + "ns");
    }


    private static class FibonacciThread implements Runnable {
        int index;
        int result;
        ExecutorService executorService;

        public FibonacciThread(int index) {
            this.index = index;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                this.result = fibonacciSum(index, executorService);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Thread interupted");
            }
        }
    }

    private static int fibonacciSum(int index, ExecutorService executorService)
            throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        if (index <= 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {

            FibonacciThread fibonacciThread1 = new FibonacciThread(index - 2);
            fibonacciThread1.executorService = executorService;
            Future future = executorService.submit(fibonacciThread1);
            Object object = future.get();
            int resultPart2 = fibonacciSum(index - 1, executorService);
            int result = fibonacciThread1.result + resultPart2;
            // executorService.shutdown();
            return result;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would it have killed you to spell out "number"? Also, there's a closed-form expression for the n^th Fibonnacci number, perhaps that'll be of interest to you.

Comment: I would just double `availableProcessors`, that would give plenty of threads with little overhead.

Comment: @Daniel - that is is a good general rule of thumb.  But in this case the algorithm will block if there aren't enough threads, and the required number of threads depends on the problem size; see my answer.

Comment: i seriously doubt you can go better than a loop and a single thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you haven't already realized this, Fibonacci numbers are not a good candidate for parallelization.  You will get (increasingly) better performance:

- by using a single threaded recursive algorithm,
- by using a single threaded recursive algorithm with *memoization*, and
- by solving the recurrence relation and implementing the resulting formula.

---

The basic problem is that the naive Fibonacci calculation requires an exponential number of computation steps.  You can't make an impact on that (in terms of performance) with multi-threading because you have a bounded number of processors.

Even if you did have an infinite number of processors, the thread setup / task creation overheads exceed the time for doing a step in the calculation.

Finally, there is a particular problem with doing Fibonacci using the executor service and a bounded thread pool.  If the thread pool is too small (or N is too large) the computation is liable to get stuck.  For instance, the way that you've coded it needs `~N` threads in the pool to calculate `fibonacci(N)`, even though most of them will be blocked most of the time.  (The best way to understand this is to "hand execute" the application, paying attention to how many threads are in use at each point in time ... and what they are doing.)

---

So the simple answer to your question is (for this particular application) that you need at least `N` threads in the pool to even complete the computation of `Fibonacci(N)`.  (This is not a general answer.  It is mandated by the details of the algorithm that you've implemented.)

---

There are lots of other SO questions / answers on calculating Fibonacci numbers using threads.  I suggest you read them as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody for the feedback.

Comment: I can't imagine why everybody doesn't have this problem. I wrote myself a self tuning thread pool to deal with this, so that it keeps adding threads until it starts to hurt performance, then it backs off. Which makes me wonder why there isn't such a thing in the standard libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an existing formula for how many threads to create. You have to look at factors such as I/O. If your thread is going to be blocked on I/O calls (which are much, much slower), then the CPU can run another thread during that time. On the other hand, if your threads are computation heavy, and require little/no I/O, then matching the number of threads to the number of cores is a good idea, as you prevent the overhead of switching between threads.

Answer (score 1):

One important factor to consider for the optimal number of threads is the degree of parallelism in the problem.  For a problem where you can only perform say 4 tasks at a time there is no point having more than 4 threads (and it may even be slower)

As you know the formula for the fibonacci series is

```
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)
```

The only degrees of parallelism are for values below 3.  For numbers greater than this each value cannot be calculated until the previous value has.  This means the optimal number of thread is one and only one.

You might say, why might more thread appear to improve performance.  This would be because you have taken an inefficient strategy and its the inefficiencies you are speeding up.

If you take the most efficient strategy from the start, the optimal number of threads is one.

Answer (score 0):

No formula, because it depends on your problem, your operating system, etc.  You'll reach a point where the overhead of context switching doesn't help your cause.  If every task is the same, more threads on the same process will just mean context switching.

Best to experiment your way to an optimum here.